# What am I doing wrong utilizing this QR Code Generator Library?

Tags: javascript, qr-code

Super noob here. I'm trying to take info from a few input fields on my website and dynamically generate a QR Code, I've found [this library](https://www.nayuki.io/page/qr-code-generator-library) which looks perfect for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I've tried copying what seems to be the relevant bits from the sample page (below), if I can get it working I can figure out the rest, but it doesn't seem to work.

Again, pardon my noobiness.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="canonical" href="https://www.nayuki.io/page/qr-code-generator-library" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <textarea xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" placeholder="Enter your text to be put into the QR Code" id="text-input" style="width:100%; max-width:30em; height:5em; font-family:inherit"></textarea>

    <canvas xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="qrcode-canvas" style="" width="232" height="232"></canvas>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="qrcode-svg" style="width:30em; height:30em; display:none" stroke="none">
                            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <path d="" fill="#000000"/>
      <rect xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
      <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="" fill="#000000"/>
    </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us what YOU have got - we can't guess what mistakes you may have made when copying an example. Some explanation of what DOES happen would also be useful "does not work" is too vague

Comment: you don't seem to be loading any library at all

Comment: @MikeBrockington This is the code I'm trying to get working, I've just attempted to copy it from a live working example.

The QR code doesn't draw, but it does appear to have some space reserved on the page for where it should go.

Comment: @Bravo am I not loading it with this line?

```<link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="canonical" href="https://www.nayuki.io/page/qr-code-generator-library" />```

Comment: no - what you've copied is *A canonical link element is an HTML element that helps webmasters prevent duplicate content issues by specifying the "canonical" or "preferred" version of a web page as part of search engine optimization*

Comment: At the moment, the code shown above is just SVG embedded in an HTML document. No CSS and definitely no JavaScript